# Pycharm and other packages don't appear in the apt-cache search list

Tags: apt, package-management, apt-cache

I can find PyCharm Pro, PyCharm CE, and PyCharm EDU in Ubuntu Software app, but I am trying to get better with `apt-get` commands in a terminal window.  Yet when I type

```
apt-cache search PyCharm
```

I am unable to see it in the list that is returned.  Is some software not available through `apt-get`?  Do I need to connect to some repository to complete my `apt-cache` list?

I have been using Linux for 2 days.  Thanks!

Comment: sudo snap install [pycharm-professional|pycharm-community] --classic is posted to pycharms website but i'm specifically looking for a way to get this information through the terminal window

Answer (score 3):

In Ubuntu `Pycharm` is only available to install as a snap package and is not in official Ubuntu repositories. So you can't find it using, `apt` or `apt-cache`, you have to use `snap` or gnome softwares GUI.

Simply use:

```
snap search pycharm
```

Answer (score 0):

I just download the tar.gz file from the JetBrains site

```
https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/?fromIDE=#section=linux
```

and then extract it; I actually put it into a ~/software directory for convenience.

You will have to set up your own desktop launcher etc. When you run it it does check for updates and gives you a message when one is available, either as a patch or a new version that needs a new .tar.gz download.

I've been using it in Xubuntu for many years with other JetBrains tools.

graham